# Increasing efficiency on a network randomization algorithm on Julia

Tags: for-loop, recursion, julia

My problem is the following. I have the adjacency matrix `Mat` for a neural network. I want to randomize this network in the sense that I want to choose 4 notes randomly (say i,j,p,q) such that i and p are connected (which means `Mat[p,i] = 1`) and j and q are connected AND i and q are not connected (`Mat[q,j] = 0`)and j and p are not connected. I then connect i and q and j and p and disconnect the previous nodes. In one run, I want to do this 10^6 times.

So far I have two versions, one using a `for` loop and one recursively.

```
newmat = copy(Mat)
for trial in 1:Niter
        count = 0
        while count < 1
            i,j,p,q = sample(Nodes,4,replace = false) #Choosing 4 nodes at random   
            if (newmat[p,i] == 1 && newmat[q,j] == 1) && (newmat[p,j] == 0 && newmat[q,i] == 0)
                newmat[p,i] = 0
                newmat[q,j] = 0
                newmat[p,j] = 1
                newmat[q,i] = 1
                count += 1
            end 
        end
end
```

Doing this recursively runs about just as fast until `Niter` = 10^4 after which I get a Stack Overflow error. How can I improve this?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about a recursive variant of the `for trial in 1:Niter`.

To avoid stack overflows like this, a general rule of thumb (in languages without tail recursion elimination) is to not use recursion unless you know the recursion depth will not scale more than logarithmically.

The cases where this is applicable is mostly algorithms that are like tree traversals, with a "naturally occuring" recursive structure.  Your case of a simple for loop can be viewed as the degenerate variant of that, with a "linked list" tree, but is not a all natural.

Just don't do it.  There's nothing bad about a loop for some sequential processing like this.  Julia is an imperative language, after all.

(If you want to do this with a recursive structure for fun or exercise: look up *trampolines*.  They allow you to write code structured as tail recursive, but with the allocation happening by mutation and on the heap.)

Comment: The reason I want to write it recursively, or at least in a better fashion is because this randomization is part of a larger program and I would have to roughly run this function 10^6 times, over ~ 750 trials. Running it once with Niter = 10^4 with the for loop takes about 5s, 10^5 takes 75s (both from `@btime` so if I run it to 10^6 it would take at least 10 mins for one randomization when I would need to do it ~ 750 x 10^8 times, apart from the run time of the rest of the program.

Comment: recursion won't make your code faster.

Comment: You just need a better algorithm.

Comment: @OscarSmith, hence my question.

Comment: The algorithm is inherently linear: `Niter` times the expected time to find an allowed combination of the four nodes. I don't think there's anything you can do implementation-wise to reduce the complexity. The only approach I can think of is to exploit known structure of the graph to make the search for the four nodes constant, but then that's still a constant reduction.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of sampling 4 random nodes and hoping they happen to be connected, you can sample the starting nodes `p` and `q`, and look for `i` and `j` within the nodes that these are connected to. Here's an implementation of that:

```
function randomizeconnections(adjmatin)
  adjmat = copy(adjmatin)
  nodes = axes(adjmat, 2)
  niter = 10
  for trial in 1:niter
    p, q = sample(nodes, 2, replace = false)
    @views plist, qlist = findall(adjmat[p, :]), findall(adjmat[q, :])
    filter!(i -> !in(i, qlist) && i != q, plist)
    filter!(j -> !in(j, plist) && j != p, qlist)
    if isempty(plist) || isempty(qlist) 
      @debug "No swappable exclusive target nodes for source nodes $p and $q, skipping trial $trial..." 
      continue 
    end
    i = rand(plist)
    j = rand(qlist)
    adjmat[p, i] = adjmat[q, j] = false
    adjmat[p, j] = adjmat[q, i] = true
  end
  adjmat
end
```

Through the course of randomization, it may happen that two nodes don't *have* any swappable connections i.e. they may share all their end points or one's ending nodes are a subset of the other's. So there's a check for that in the above code, and the loop moves on to the next iteration in that case.

The line with the `findall`s in the above code effectively creates adjacency lists from the adjacency matrix on the fly. You can instead do that in one go at the beginning, and work with that adjacency list vector instead.

```
function randomizeconnections2(adjmatin)
  adjlist = [findall(r) for r in eachrow(adjmatin)]
  nodes = axes(adjlist, 1)
  niter = 10
  for trial in 1:niter
    p, q = sample(nodes, 2, replace = false)
    plist = filter(i -> !in(i, adjlist[q]) && i != q, adjlist[p])
    qlist = filter(j -> !in(j, adjlist[p]) && j != p, adjlist[q])
    if isempty(plist) || isempty(qlist) 
      @debug "No swappable exclusive target nodes for source nodes $p and $q, skipping trial $trial..." 
      continue 
    end
    i = rand(plist)
    j = rand(qlist)
    replace!(adjlist[p], i => j)
    replace!(adjlist[q], j => i)
  end
  create_adjmat(adjlist)
end


function create_adjmat(adjlist::Vector{Vector{Int}})
   adjmat = falses(length(adjlist), length(adjlist))
   for (i, l) in pairs(adjlist)
     adjmat[i, l] .= true
   end
   adjmat
end
```

With the small matriced I tried locally, `randomizeconnections2` seems about twice as fast as `randomizeconnections`, but you may want to confirm whether that's the case with your matrix sizes and values.

Both of these accept (and were tested with) `BitMatrix` type values as input, which should be more efficient than an ordinary matrix of booleans or integers.

Comment: This doesn't give the same distribution of random nodes.

Comment: I'm not sure the exact distribution matters for an ML application like this. (Though, I would appreciate any recommendations on any theoretical treatment of the two ways and what distributions they end up with. It reminds me of [this LightGraphs.jl issue thread](https://github.com/sbromberger/LightGraphs.jl/issues/1208) I came across some time ago, which is broadly similar afaict.)